# Excel VBA large data runtime issue

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I have large scale data (700K rows), and I'm trying to count the number
of appearance of a word within the rows, and do so for also many times (50K iterations).
I'm wondering if Excel is appropriate platform, using VBA or maybe COUNTIFS, or should I use different Platform? 
If so, is there a platform that has similarity points to Excel and VBA?
Thanks!

Comment: if that 'word' you need to count could be a part of text in any cell then try to explore `Range.Find` property (there have been few examples recently here in SO). If there is only 'word' within cell then simply use `CountIf/CountIfs` function (as you suggest).

Comment: Is your data already in Excel, or is it somewhere else? If you need to examine the frequency of 50k words then it may be easiest to first load all your words as keys in a scripting dictionary and then run though all the words in your data, checking against the dictionary and incrementing the count if found. More details on what your data looks like would help.

Comment: Seeing an example would help. PowerPivot (xl2010-13) may be a useful option

Comment: @user1869297, your comment seems to be incomplete...

Comment: The data is already in Excel. I gave an abstract description of the program, what I'm actually intending to do is: for over 50K words (when a 'word' is a small sentence), find all the appearance of the current word in a list of 700K rows (again, the values are small sentences) at column A, and for each appearance write down the value of the parallel cell at column B.

Answer (score 1):

With your small sentences in column A and the 700k lines in column A of Sheet1, this formula will count the occurrences. It's an array formula and must be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
=SUM(--NOT(ISERR(FIND(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$700000))))
```

To calculate 200 small sentences took about 20 seconds on my machine. If that's an indication, it will take about 1.5 hours to calculate 50k small sentences. You should probably find a better tool or at least hit calculate right before you leave for lunch. Definitely test it on a smaller number to make sure it gives you the answers you want. If you don't have to do this often, maybe 1.5 hours is palatable.